# Trouble understanding tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, decoder, sequence-to-sequence

I managed to build a **sequence to sequence** model in **tensorflow** using the **tf.contrib.seq2seq** classes in 1.1 version. 
 
For know I use the **TrainingHelper** for training my model.
But does this helper feed **previously decoded** values in the decoder for training or just the ground truth?
If it doesn't how can I feed previously decoded value as input in the decoder instead of ground truth values ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TrainingHelper` feeds the ground truth at every step. If you want to use decoder outputs, you can use **scheduled sampling** [1]. Scheduled sampling is implemented in `ScheduledEmbeddingTrainingHelper` and `ScheduledOutputTrainingHelper`, so you can use one of the two (depending on your particular application) instead of `TrainingHelper`. See also this thread here: 
[scheduled sampling in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795423/scheduled-sampling-in-tensorflow).

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03099.pdf