# How to use "ScheduledOutputTrainingSampler" in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In tensorflow, there's a method called `ScheduledOutputTrainingSampler` defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/ScheduledOutputTrainingSampler). It basically adds scheduled sampling to the outputs of an LSTM model.

I've been struggling to understand how to use this function in a simple stacked LSTM model.

To add more details, I have a simple stacked LSTM architecture defined below:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Input, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


def define_model(num_features, rnn_size, output_size):
    x = Input(shape=(None, num_features))
    y = LSTM(rnn_size, return_sequences=True)(x)
    y = LSTM(rnn_size, return_sequences=True)(y)
    y = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_size))(y)
    return Model(x, y)

train_op = define_model(num_features=17, rnn_size=120, output_size=8)
train_op.summary()
train_op.fit(X_train, y_train) # X_train: (100, 8, 17), y_train: (100, 8, 8)
```

and the model summary will result in

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_36 (InputLayer)       [(None, None, 17)]        0         
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (None, None, 120)         66240     
                                                                 
 lstm_3 (LSTM)               (None, None, 120)         115680    
                                                                 
 time_distributed (TimeDistr  (None, None, 8)          968       
 ibuted)                                                         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 182,888
Trainable params: 182,888
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

In the above code, I need to make use of `ScheduledOutputTrainingSampler` such that for every `LSTMCell`, the output is sampled from both ground truth and predicted values depending on the sampling probability. I know that we'll have to use `LSTMCell` instead of `LSTM` but I'm not able to understand how to restructure this architecture to make it work.

Simply stated, how do I incorporate `ScheduledOutputTrainingSampler` for the above model architecture?